# How to get a file without knowing its extension - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file

There is a file in folder "Images" in server.

The file's name is "jason", but I don't know if it is "jason.pdf" or "jason.jpg" or "jason.png".. However the file must have one of these extensions : ".pdf, .png, .jpg". There is no other option.

I know I can get the file like this if I know its extension is ".pdf" :

```
<a href="~/Images/jason.pdf">File</a>
```

But I don't know what to do if I don't know its extension. How can I get the file without knowing its extension but knowing only file name? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create an image controller which will search that folder for that file name and return that.

Comment: @Shyju So, should I call that controller from the View? An example would be awesome.. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider creating an controller action which serves you these files.

Here is a quick-working-simple example. Feel free to edit it to make it ophisticated & robust as needed.

```
public class ImageController:Controller
{
    private string GetFilePath(string fileName)
    {
        var path = Server.MapPath(Url.Content("~/Images"));
        //Getting all the files present in this directory
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(path);

        // Loop through each items(filenames) and  check the filename(without extension)
        // is matching with our method parameter value
        foreach(var file in files)
        {
            if(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)
                   .Equals(fileName,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                return file;
            }
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
    [Route("image/{fileName}")]
    public ActionResult GetFile(string fileName)
    {
        var path = GetFilePath(fileName);
        // to do : handle if path is string.empty
        // may be return default content/file ?
        var contentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(path);
        byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
        return File(bytes, contentType);
    }
}
```

Now in your other view, you will call this as

```
<a href="~/Image/jason">PDF File</a>
```

Or

```
 <a href="~/Image/puppy">Image file name</a>
```

Here we are using attribute routing for our method so that the request to `/image/{filename}` will be mapped to the `GetFile` method. Make sure you have attribute routing enabled by calling `MapMvcAttributeRoutes` method inside `RegisterRoutes` method of `RouteConfig.cs`.

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");                    
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        //Existing default route defnition goes here           
    }
}
```

**Few things to consider**

1. The above simple implementation is reading all the files in the Images directory every time the action method is invoked. You should **consider caching** the results(list of file names, return value of `GetFiles`) so that you can avoid making the call all the time. You can store it in an in memory cache/ database etc.
2. If user is passing a file name which does not exist in the location, what do you want to return. The `GetFilePath` method above returns `string.empty` in that case. Handle it inside the `GetFile` method.
3. The `Directory.GetFiles` method has an overload which takes a search pattern. You may consider using that and totally get rid of the `foreach` loop.
4. If you are serving static file (ex :`/images/file.jpg`) , IIS will serve the file (without executing any MVC code. That will be faster).
5. Explore caching options and see how that can make your experience even faster.

Comment: One stupid question: How can I use this controller from View? Thank you so much...

Comment: Downvoter, care to comment ? That will help me to learn something new :)