# How to handle a controller result that returns a file in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a controller that returns a file like this :

```
byte[] fileBytes=System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/"), photoPath));
            string fileName = prop;
            return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
```

I can display it in HTML image like this

```
<div class="col-md-6"><img src="@("File/Download?id="+ Model.ID+"&prop=photo")" alt="Image" /></div>
```

I want to create a link using that controller, so that when user clicks it, it will show the image :

```
    <div class="col-md-4"><a @(Model.path == null ? Html.ActionLink("click here", "Download", "File", new { appid = Model.ID.ToString(), prop = "photo" }, null) : Html.ActionLink("none", "", ""))</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Html.ActionLink` helper method will generate HTML markup for the anchor tag. Does not make sense to call it inside the opening `a` tag

A simple `If` condition can do.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  @if(Model.path == null)
  {
      @Html.ActionLink("click here", "Download", "File", 
                                     new { appid = Model.ID, prop = "photo" }, null); 
  }
  else
  {
    <span>Nothing to download or even another link you can use here</span>
  }
</div>
```

Comment: It worked but the downloaded file type looks like a generic file. How can I make it specific like .pdf or .jpg? How should I modify the controller? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: You need to fix your action method to send the correct content/mime type.For the image, get the content type using `MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fileName);` method and use that. Refer the `GetFile` method in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53144403/how-to-get-a-file-without-knowing-its-extension-asp-net-mvc/53144674#53144674)